# How to see all icons in dash home?

Tags: icons, unity-dash

When clicked on Dash home, it shows only recent icons
I want to see all the installed application Icons when clicked on Dash home....
And can I increase the size of the Dash home window? Because it occupies only 1/4th of the screen.

Is there any way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Increasing Dash Size**

[image]

**Applications Lens**

[image]

1 Opens the applications lens; shortcut: `Super` + `A` (Super = Windows key)

2 Expands the visible apps

3 Lets you filter the listed applications by categories

Hold down `Super` for more Unity tricks.